# Component not rendered after promise with data resolves

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a component BagPage that has some child components that will render after the getBagByIdAsync promise resolves and I want to add a click event listener to some elements inside one of this child components right after they are rendered but keep getting:

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

this means I'm trying to add the event listener before the elements exist in the DOM.

here's my code:

```
function listenToBagRemove(bag) {
    bag.items.forEach(item => {
        document
            .querySelector(`#remove${item.id}`)
            .addEventListener('click', () => {
                return BagService.deleteItemByIdAsync(bagId, item.id);
            });
    });
}

async function BagPage(bagId) {
let bag;

try {
    bag = await BagService.getBagByIdAsync(bagId).then(res => {
        listenToBagRemove(res);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return '<div class="error">Error loading bag items...</div>';
}

return `<div class="page">
            ${Header(bag.items)}
            ${ProductsList(bag.items)}
            ${Footer()}
        </div>`;
}

export default BagPage;
```

and the code for each product card inside the product list:

```
const ProductCard = item => `<div class="product-card">
                <div class="remove-btn" id="remove${item.id}">
                    <img src="${closeIcon}" />
                </div>
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img class="image" src="${item.image}" />
                </div>
                <div class="info-container alignCenter">
                    <div class="brandName">${item.name}</div>
                    <div class="price">€${item.price}</div>
                </div>
            </div>`;

export default ProductCard;
```

Comment: I don't think your `await` statement is "waiting" for the asynchronous response, but rather for the chained `.then` call. Try doing something like `let res = await BagService.getBagByIdAsync(bagId); bag = listenToBagRemove(res);`

Comment: It is resolving, I can see the content of res.

Comment: Are you sure the buttons have the correct id? `#remove${item.id}`.

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Comment: Since you seem to return some HTML snippet, doesn't this mean you try adding the events Before the HTML has been returned? Or does the returned HTML have nothing to do with your bag items? I would expect the `.then( listenToBagRemove )` to appear somewhere After the HTML has been added to the DOM, not inside the BagPage function that creates the HTML but does not insert it into the DOM before trying to add event listeners.